# How to find the square of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be the linear transformation defined by the system

$y_1 =-3x_1+x_2$

$y_2 =x_1-x_2$.

I was trying to find a system of linear equations defining the linear transformation of $T^2$
Then the solutions I got are $y_1=10x_1-4x_2$ and $y_2=-4x_1+2x_2$ 
(where $x$ and $y$ are variables). Would someone help verifying the solutions?

Comment: It looks good to me. You can verify by just computing $T^2(1,0)^T$ and $T^2(0,1)^T$ with both methods (that is, using your solution, and by applying $T$ twice) and checking you get the same answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your result is good. You can see the same in matrix form. Your tansfromation $T$ is represented by the matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}
-3&1\\1&-1
\end{bmatrix}$
and we have:
$$
T^2=\begin{bmatrix}
-3&1\\1&-1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
-3&1\\1&-1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
10&-4\\-4&-2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Sorry! it's a typo :)

Comment: Thank you for the verification but could T be a one-to-one